# Android - Show set wallpaper button when image selected

Tags: java, android

i want to create wallpaper app.
i want user click image show whole image and visible set wallpaper button.
like this pictures
[image]

after licked like this
[image]

The problem is to show set wallpaper button when image clicked and show whole image.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. to display  all image display activity use `recyclerview` with `GridLayoutManager`like this

   > private GridLayoutManager lLayout;
   >   lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2);
   >   recyclerview.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

check this link for [how to use recyclerview with GridLayoutManager](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)

2. for display image create a new activity and pass the image when user select image from recyclerview to that activity and display

**Ask me in case of any query**